# How can I create a Lua macro in AutoHotKey that repeats a sequence of key presses when a certain key is pressed?

Tags: autohotkey

i want to create a macro via lua in AutoHotKey that when run, i can press a assigned key to execute a sequence of key presses that repeats until i let go of the assigned key. i am a total noob in coding but after searching a bit on google i only figured out the code for the sequence of key presses (or most of it). Can anyone help me finish this?

for example: press (v) to execute this sequence below repeatedly until i let go of (v). Also the macro has to stop outputting inputs the moment i let go of (v) instead of finishing the entire sequence before stopping

```
PressKey(j) 
Sleep(30)
ReleaseKey(j)
Sleep(30)
PressKey(k)
Sleep(30)
ReleaseKey(k)
Sleep(30)
PressKey(s)
Sleep(20)
PressKey(k)
Sleep(30)
ReleaseKey(k)
Sleep(20)
ReleaseKey(s)
```

Comment: AHK does not support Lua.  It uses its own language for scripts.

Comment: i found some video on youtube but even if i didnt exactly like in the video there's always errors. I got some simple line to work like v::Send "j" is going to turn my "v" key into the "j" key but i couldnt figure out how to code the sleep function correctly. I also want the macro to hold certain key for me before releasing (down and up function). Can you help me with it? for example: pressing v will trigger a macro that press j>wait 50ms>release j>wait 50ms>press k>wait 50ms>release k

Comment: I dont use AHK.  You can try searching for more AHR tutorials or ask on AHK-related forums.  Or wait until someone answers here.

Comment: Have you tried using HammerSpoon? HammerSpoon is built on Lua and the eventtap keystrokes module might be what you're looking for: https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.eventtap.html#keyStrokes